# After div is scrolled to the end the whole page becames scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs:

```
<div id="slide1">
<div id="wrapper">
```

What I want to do is that when the page is loaded wrapper in fixed position and it only becomes static when slide1 div is scrolled to the bottom which is partly hidden under wrapper div and if I scroll up wrapper becomes fixed again. Furthermore, when slide1 is scrolled to the bottom I want to make it go up with wrapper div together nice and smooth without any jumping and responsive also.
I have made this javascript code and it worked almost fine but was not responsive (I don't remember exactly how I thinked of if statment it was quite long time ago):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var a = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(a*2 >= ($(window).height())+900) {
        $(".wrapper").css({'position' : 'static' });
        $("#slide1").css({'height' : 1600});
   } else {
        $(".wrapper").css({'position' : 'fixed' });
        $("#slide1").css({'height' : 2000});

   }
});
```

Comment: Can you fiddle it  (https://jsfiddle.net/ ) ? So that we can easily check what have you done.

Comment: This is how it looks like now: http://fas-web.sunderland.ac.uk/~bg85ie/portfolio/index.html

Comment: It seems to be working correctly.. What's the issue ?

Comment: I don't know how to make it work for mobiles